# Mongo / Mongoose - Aggregating by Date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo/mongoose schema which when queried retruns documents such as

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49ac"), "amount" : -33.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-04-26T23:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.581Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49ba"), "amount" : -61.3, "name" : "Amazon", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-23T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.592Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49ce"), "amount" : -3.3, "name" : "Tesco", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-15T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.601Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49cc"), "amount" : -26.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-16T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.600Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49f7"), "amount" : -63.3, "name" : "Sky", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-02T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.617Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49be"), "amount" : -3.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-22T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.593Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
```

I would like to write a query what provides the yearly, monthly and weekly spend for each of the vendors (`"name" : "Amazon"`), so for example for vendor RINGGO:

- There are three spends in 2017 33.3+26.3+3.3 so total yearly spend would be 59.9
- There are two spends in the month 2017-03 with a sum of 26.3+3.3 so the monthly total would be 26.6
- Each of the spends are in different weeks so the weekly totals would be (for example) wk12 26.3, wk13 3.3, wk 15 33.3

I can write a query such as

```
db.statements.aggregate(
   [        
       { $group : { _id : "$name", amount: { $push: "$amount" } } }
   ]
)
```

which will aggregate all spends (`amount`) by vendor name, but I'm not sure how to break this down by year, month, week as described above.

Edit in response to comment
I'm not exactly sure that shape the result may have but ideally it would be something like the below:

I need the year, month, week etc so that the queries can be driven by url (e.g. `domain.com/vendorname/2017`, `domain.com/vendorname/2017/3`, `domain.com/vendorname/2017/3/12`)

I would also like both the individual spends and the total spends for each year/month/week as I would like to print these to the page.

```
{ "_id" : 
    { "year" : 2017, 
      "month" : 3, 
      "week" : 12 }, 
    "name": "RINGGO", //vendor name
    "YearlySpends":[ 33.3, 26.3, 3.3] 
    "totalYearlylyAmount" : [ 59.9] 
    "MonthlySpends":[ 26.3, 3.3] 
    "totalMonthlyAmount" : [ 26.6] 
    "WeeklylySpends":[ 3.3] 
    "totalWeeklylyAmount" : [3.3] 

}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could add your expected result JSON to supplement the sample data, that way the aggregate pipeline can be easily inferred using that expected output.

Comment: @chridam I have edited the question with an attempt at what I would like the result JSON to look like

Comment: By the way `33.3+26.3+3.3 = 62.9` not `59.9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach would be to break the aggregate pipeline into several steps with the aim of calculating the aggregates with each group i.e. yearly, monthly and weekly aggregates.

I've made a feeble attempt at generating the said pipeline but not sure if that's what you are after but could give you some leads to a solution, better yet an optimal one. Perhaps someone else could give a better answer.

Consider the following *untested* pipeline:

```
db.statements.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "name": "$name",
                "year": { "$year": "$date" },
                "month": { "$month": "$date" },
                "week": { "$week": "$date" }
            },
            "total": { "$sum": "$amount" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "name": "$_id.name",
                "year": "$_id.year"
            },
            "YearlySpends": { "$push": "$total" },
            "totalYearlyAmount": { "$sum": "$total" },
            "data": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "name": "$_id.name",
                "month": "$data._id.month"
            },
            "YearlySpends": { "$first": "$YearlySpends" },
            "totalYearlyAmount": { "$first": "$totalYearlyAmount" },
            "MonthlySpends": { "$push": "$data.total" },
            "totalMonthlyAmount": { "$sum": "$data.total" },
            "data": { "$push": "$data" }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "name": "$_id.name",
                "week": "$data._id.week"
            },
            "YearlySpends": { "$first": "$YearlySpends" },
            "totalYearlyAmount": { "$first": "$totalYearlyAmount" },
            "MonthlySpends": { "$first": "$MonthlySpends" },
            "totalMonthlyAmount": { "$first": "$totalMonthlyAmount" },
            "WeeklySpends": { "$push": "$data.total" },
            "totalWeeklyAmount": { "$sum": "$data.total" },
            "data": { "$push": "$data" }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$data._id",
            "YearlySpends": { "$first": "$YearlySpends" },
            "totalYearlyAmount": { "$first": "$totalYearlyAmount" },
            "MonthlySpends": { "$first": "$MonthlySpends" },
            "totalMonthlyAmount": { "$first": "$totalMonthlyAmount" },
            "WeeklySpends": { "$first": "$WeeklySpends" },
            "totalWeeklyAmount": { "$first": "$totalWeeklyAmount" }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "Tesco",
        "year" : 2017,
        "month" : 3,
        "week" : 11
    },
    "YearlySpends" : [ 
        -3.3
    ],
    "totalYearlyAmount" : -3.3,
    "MonthlySpends" : [ 
        -3.3
    ],
    "totalMonthlyAmount" : -3.3,
    "WeeklySpends" : [ 
        -3.3
    ],
    "totalWeeklyAmount" : -3.3
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "RINGGO",
        "year" : 2017,
        "month" : 4,
        "week" : 17
    },
    "YearlySpends" : [ 
        -3.3, 
        -26.3, 
        -33.3
    ],
    "totalYearlyAmount" : -62.9,
    "MonthlySpends" : [ 
        -33.3
    ],
    "totalMonthlyAmount" : -33.3,
    "WeeklySpends" : [ 
        -33.3
    ],
    "totalWeeklyAmount" : -33.3
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "RINGGO",
        "year" : 2017,
        "month" : 3,
        "week" : 12
    },
    "YearlySpends" : [ 
        -3.3, 
        -26.3, 
        -33.3
    ],
    "totalYearlyAmount" : -62.9,
    "MonthlySpends" : [ 
        -3.3, 
        -26.3
    ],
    "totalMonthlyAmount" : -29.6,
    "WeeklySpends" : [ 
        -3.3
    ],
    "totalWeeklyAmount" : -3.3
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "RINGGO",
        "year" : 2017,
        "month" : 3,
        "week" : 11
    },
    "YearlySpends" : [ 
        -3.3, 
        -26.3, 
        -33.3
    ],
    "totalYearlyAmount" : -62.9,
    "MonthlySpends" : [ 
        -3.3, 
        -26.3
    ],
    "totalMonthlyAmount" : -29.6,
    "WeeklySpends" : [ 
        -26.3
    ],
    "totalWeeklyAmount" : -26.3
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "Sky",
        "year" : 2017,
        "month" : 3,
        "week" : 9
    },
    "YearlySpends" : [ 
        -63.3
    ],
    "totalYearlyAmount" : -63.3,
    "MonthlySpends" : [ 
        -63.3
    ],
    "totalMonthlyAmount" : -63.3,
    "WeeklySpends" : [ 
        -63.3
    ],
    "totalWeeklyAmount" : -63.3
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "Amazon",
        "year" : 2017,
        "month" : 3,
        "week" : 12
    },
    "YearlySpends" : [ 
        -61.3
    ],
    "totalYearlyAmount" : -61.3,
    "MonthlySpends" : [ 
        -61.3
    ],
    "totalMonthlyAmount" : -61.3,
    "WeeklySpends" : [ 
        -61.3
    ],
    "totalWeeklyAmount" : -61.3
}
```

---

### UPDATE

If you wish to include filters within the aggregate operation then I would suggest you use the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** query as the first pipeline stage. However, if there is an initial **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** step then the preceding steps would be altered slightly as you will be aggregating filtered results, very different from aggregating all the documents as a whole initially and then applying the filter on the results.

---

If you are to take the *filter-first-then-aggregate* route, consider running an aggregate operation that uses **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** as the first step which filters the documents by vendor, then a preceding **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline step to further filter the documents on the month part of the date field and then the rest would be the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stages:

```
Statements.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": req.params.vendor } },
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$date" }, parseInt(req.params.month) ]},
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    },
    .....
    /*
        add the remaining pipeline steps after
    */
], function(err, data){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
})
```

If you are to take the *group-first-then-filter* route, then the filter would be after the last pipeline that gives the grouped result but applied on different fields as the documents down that part of the stream would be different from the original schema.

This route is not performant since you are beginning the aggregate operation with all the documents in the collection and then filtering afterwards:

```
Statements.aggregate([
    .....
    /*
        place the initial pipeline steps from 
        the original query above here
    */
    .....
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "_id.name": req.params.vendor,
            "_id.month": parseInt(req.params.month)
        } 
    }
], function(err, data){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
})
```

---

For multiple date filter parameters, the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** operator would be

```
{
    "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            {
                "$and": [
                     { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$date" },  parseInt(req.params.year)  ]},
                     { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$date" }, parseInt(req.params.month) ]},
                     { "$eq": [{ "$week": "$date" },  parseInt(req.params.week)  ]}
                ]
            },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: that looks fantastic thanks!  Is it valid for me to add on`,{
             $match : {
                 "_id.month" : 3,
                 "_id.week" :12,
                 "name" : "RINGGO"
             }
         }`?  so that I can use `req.params.vendor`, `req.params.month` etc to drive the results?  Also of the above three matches only `_id.month` and `_id.month` rturn successfully. As soon as I add `"name" : "RINGGO"` (even if that is all that is in the match) then i get no results even though I see that there are records with a name of RINGGO

Comment: Thanks for this.  Agree that it's best to filter-first-then-aggregate.  I tried to modify so that I could query for a particular month in a year:

`"$cond": [
    { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$date" }, parseInt(req.params.year) ]},
          { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$date" }, 3parseInt(req.params.month) ]},  
          "$$KEEP",
          "$$PRUNE"
        ]`

but got 
`"errmsg" : "Expression $cond takes exactly 3 arguments. 4 were passed in."`

Comment: This would be fine if there was only one year (2017) because I could assume wk12 is unique but when 2018 rolls around how do I pass all the required details (down to week I suppose) to ensure I am getting the data for only a particular month in a year or particular week in a particular month in a particular year?

Comment: @StuartBrown Updated

Comment: Thank you so much! That is the most fantastically-answered question!

Comment: Hi @chridam. I hope you don't mind me coming back on this but I've had a chance to look at this after recovering from an illness.  Is there a way to modify the query so that if i am just passing a year and month (or just a year)  `{
                "$and": [
                     { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$date" },  parseInt(req.params.year)  ]},
                     { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$date" }, parseInt(req.params.month) ]}
                ]
            },` that I just get back one record?  currently i get four, one for each week in the month and all monthly and yearly data is the same

Comment: There's something else I've noticed about the query.  If so example I run a simple find by name in mongo shell for a particular vendor I will get `.."amount" : -1.8, "name" : "BARTLETT MITCHELL"
"amount" : -3.25, "name" : "BARTLETT MITCHELL"
"amount" : -1.8, "name" : "BARTLETT MITCHELL"
"amount" : -1.8, "name" : "BARTLETT MITCHELL"
"amount" : -1.8, "name" : "BARTLETT MITCHELL" ..` but when I run the query above i see in console that I get `MonthlySpends: [ -1.8, -3.6, -5.05 ],
  totalMonthlyAmount: -10.45,` which is incorrect