# Mongo / Mongoose Aggregation - $redact and $cond issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I was fortunate enough to get an awesome answer to another SO question [Mongo / Mongoose - Aggregating by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864813/mongo-mongoose-aggregating-by-date) from @chridam which given a set of documents like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49ac"), "amount" : -33.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-04-26T23:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.581Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49ba"), "amount" : -61.3, "name" : "Amazon", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-23T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.592Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49ce"), "amount" : -3.3, "name" : "Tesco", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-15T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.601Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49cc"), "amount" : -26.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-16T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.600Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49f7"), "amount" : -63.3, "name" : "Sky", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-02T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.617Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49be"), "amount" : -3.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-22T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.593Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
```

required a query that would aggregate the spend by vendor, year, month and week.  The query is below and it almost works fantastically but as I have used it in my application I have noticed a significant problem

```
db.statements.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "name": "RINGGO" } },
  {
  "$redact": {
      "$cond": [
          {
              "$and": [
                 { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$date" },  2017  ]}, // within my route this uses parseInt(req.params.year)
                 { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$date" }, 3 ]}, // within my route this uses parseInt(req.params.month)
                 { "$eq": [{ "$week": "$date" },  12  ]} // within my route this uses parseInt(req.params.week)
            ]
        },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
    ]
}
},{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "name": "$name",
            "year": { "$year": "$date" },
            "month": { "$month": "$date" },
            "week": { "$week": "$date" }
        },
        "total": { "$sum": "$amount" }
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "name": "$_id.name",
            "year": "$_id.year"
        },
        "YearlySpends": { "$push": "$total" },
        "totalYearlyAmount": { "$sum": "$total" },
        "data": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
    }
},
{ "$unwind": "$data" },
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "name": "$_id.name",
            "month": "$data._id.month"
        },
        "YearlySpends": { "$first": "$YearlySpends" },
        "totalYearlyAmount": { "$first": "$totalYearlyAmount" },
        "MonthlySpends": { "$push": "$data.total" },
        "totalMonthlyAmount": { "$sum": "$data.total" },
        "data": { "$push": "$data" }
    }
},
{ "$unwind": "$data" },
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "name": "$_id.name",
            "week": "$data._id.week"
        },
        "YearlySpends": { "$first": "$YearlySpends" },
        "totalYearlyAmount": { "$first": "$totalYearlyAmount" },
        "MonthlySpends": { "$first": "$MonthlySpends" },
        "totalMonthlyAmount": { "$first": "$totalMonthlyAmount" },
        "WeeklySpends": { "$push": "$data.total" },
        "totalWeeklyAmount": { "$sum": "$data.total" },
        "data": { "$push": "$data" }
    }
},
{ "$unwind": "$data" },
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$data._id",
        "YearlySpends": { "$first": "$YearlySpends" },
        "totalYearlyAmount": { "$first": "$totalYearlyAmount" },
        "MonthlySpends": { "$first": "$MonthlySpends" },
        "totalMonthlyAmount": { "$first": "$totalMonthlyAmount" },
        "WeeklySpends": { "$first": "$WeeklySpends" },
        "totalWeeklyAmount": { "$first": "$totalWeeklyAmount" }
    }
}
])
```

Running this query returns

```
{ "_id" :
 { "name" : "RINGGO", 
   "year" : 2017, 
   "month" : 3, 
   "week" : 12 }, 
   "YearlySpends" : [ -9.6 ], 
   "totalYearlyAmount" : -9.6, 
   "MonthlySpends" : [ -9.6 ], 
   "totalMonthlyAmount" : -9.6, 
   "WeeklySpends" : [ -9.6 ], 
   "totalWeeklyAmount" : -9.6 
}
```

And when I change to wanting to see the month's spending

```
"$cond": [
          {
            "$and": [
                 { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$date" },  2017  ]},
                 { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$date" }, 3 ]}
            ]
          },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
      ]
```

I get:

```
{ "_id" : { "name" : "RINGGO", "year" : 2017, "month" : 3, "week" : 12 }, "YearlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalYearlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997, "MonthlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalMonthlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997, "WeeklySpends" : [ -9.6 ], "totalWeeklyAmount" : -9.6 }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "RINGGO", "year" : 2017, "month" : 3, "week" : 9 }, "YearlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalYearlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997, "MonthlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalMonthlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997, "WeeklySpends" : [ -3.3 ], "totalWeeklyAmount" : -3.3 }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "RINGGO", "year" : 2017, "month" : 3, "week" : 11 }, "YearlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalYearlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997, "MonthlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalMonthlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997, "WeeklySpends" : [ -9.6 ], "totalWeeklyAmount" : -9.6 }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "RINGGO", "year" : 2017, "month" : 3, "week" : 13 }, "YearlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalYearlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997, "MonthlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalMonthlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997, "WeeklySpends" : [ -3.3 ], "totalWeeklyAmount" : -3.3 }
```

However when I run a simple `db.statements.find({"name":"RINGGO"})` I get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49ac"), "amount" : -3.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-26T23:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.581Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49ba"), "amount" : -6.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-23T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.592Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49ce"), "amount" : -3.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-15T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.601Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49cc"), "amount" : -6.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-16T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.600Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49f7"), "amount" : -3.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-02T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.617Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5907a5850b459d4fdcdf49be"), "amount" : -3.3, "name" : "RINGGO", "method" : "VIS", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-22T00:00:00Z"), "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:15:49.593Z"), "category" : "Not Set", "__v" : 0 }
```

So you can see that there is a different number of items in  `MonthlySpends` in previous output compared to that shown in the output from the find by name. Also you can see that some of the values are being summed together in `MonthlySpends` when they shouldn't be.

Ideally I'm looking to get to an output which:
when I have `$redact` containing:

```
"$cond": [
        {
            "$and": [
                 { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$date" },  2017  ]}, 
                 { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$date" }, 3 ]}, 
                 { "$eq": [{ "$week": "$date" },  12  ]} 
            ]
        },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
    ]
```

returns

```
{ "_id" : { "name" : "RINGGO", "year" : 2017, "month" : 3, "week" : 12 }, "YearlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalYearlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997, "MonthlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalMonthlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997, "WeeklySpends" : [ -9.6 ], "totalWeeklyAmount" : -9.6 }
```

when I have `$redact` containing:

```
"$cond": [
        {
            "$and": [
                 { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$date" },  2017  ]}, 
                 { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$date" }, 3 ]},
            ]
        },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
        ]
```

returns

```
{ "_id" : { "name" : "RINGGO", "year" : 2017, "month" : 3 }, "YearlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalYearlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997, "MonthlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalMonthlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997 }
```

when I have `$redact` containing:

```
"$cond": [
        {
            "$and": [
                 { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$date" },  2017  ]}
            ]
        },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
        ]
```

returns

```
{ "_id" : { "name" : "RINGGO", "year" : 2017 }, "YearlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ], "totalYearlyAmount" : -25.799999999999997}
```

Any help in this much required.  I've tried tinkering with  the query but I'm afraid I just don't understand it enough to modify it correctly.

My Mongoose version is `^4.9.5` and my mongo is `3.4.2`.

Comment: Using `$redact` to filter date ranges is highly inefficient. You really should be simply querying for the "range" using `$gte` and `$lte` operators in your initial `$match` pipeline stage.

Comment: You also appear to be missing the point here that it is the subsequent `$group` stages that are gradually reducing the granularity here. I.e first rollup the week, then then all weeks in a month, months in year. If you are proposing to change the initial scope of selection to just a week or just a month, then you follow up with less `$group` stages.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for taking the time to comment! I'm quite sure that I am missing the point here.  I'm a mongo/mongoose newbie so trying to learn!  I've tried removing some of the `$group` stages but it doesn't change the number of records returned.  Also, how would this be affecting the incorrect number of items in `"MonthlySpends" : [ -3.3, -9.6, -9.6, -3.3 ]` and therefore the sum of them in `totalMonthlyAmount `?  Would you be willing to post an answer that I can test and hopefully mark as correct?

Comment: @NeilLunn perhaps the reason `$gte` and `$lte` aren't being used is that the queries are actually being driven by URL e.g. `RINGGO/2017/3/12` or  `RINGGO/2017/3`.  You can see in the question above code comments showing `parseInt(req.params.year)`, `parseInt(req.params.month)` etc

Comment: You should also add your mongodb & mongoose version for completeness.

Comment: Thanks @Veeram I have edited the question with those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$facet` with `$addFields` for parallel aggregation in `3.4` version.

This will reduce the overall complexity and you can run groupings with its own matching input at the same time.

The below code builds the aggregation pipeline dynamically based on request object.

```
// Sample request
var request = {
  "name":"RINGGO",
  "year": 2017,
  "month":3,
  "week":12
};

// Build initial match document on name

var match1 = {
  name: request["name"]
};

// Build project & facet document for date based aggregation

var addFields = {};
var facet = {};

// Add year followed by year facet

if (request["year"]) {
    addFields["year"] = { "$year": "$date" },
    facet["Yearly"] = 
      [
        {
          "$match":{ "year": request["year"] }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "name": "$name",
              "year": "$year"
            },
            "spend": { "$push":"$amount" },
            "total": { "$sum": "$amount" }
        }
      }
    ];
}

// Add month followed by month facet

if (request["month"]) {
    addFields["month"] = { "$month": "$date" };
    facet["Monthly"] = 
      [
        {
          "$match":{ "month": request["month"] }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "name": "$name",
              "month": "$month"
            },
            "spend": { "$push":"$amount" },
            "total": { "$sum": "$amount" }
         }
      }
    ];
}

// Add week followed by week facet

if (request["week"]) {
    addFields["week"] = { "$week": "$date" };
    facet["Weekly"] = 
      [
        {
          "$match":{ "week": request["week"] }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "name": "$name",
              "week": "$week"
            },
            "spend": { "$push":"$amount" },
            "total": { "$sum": "$amount" }
         }
      }
    ];
}

// Use aggregate builder

statements.aggregate()
        .match(match1)
        .append({"$addFields": addFields}) // No addFields stage in mongoose builder
        .facet(facet)
        .exec(function(err, data) {});
```

Mongo Shell Query for `name/year/month/week` criteria.

```
db.statements.aggregate({
    '$match': {
        name: 'RINGGO'
    }
}, {
    '$addFields': {
        year: {
            '$year': '$date'
        },
        month: {
            '$month': '$date'
        },
        week: {
            '$week': '$date'
        }
    }
}, {
    '$facet': {
        Yearly: [{
                '$match': {
                    year: 2017
                }
            },
            {
                '$group': {
                    _id: {
                        name: '$name',
                        year: '$year'
                    },
                    spend: {
                        '$push': '$amount'
                    },
                    total: {
                        '$sum': '$amount'
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        Monthly: [{
                '$match': {
                    month: 3
                }
            },
            {
                '$group': {
                    _id: {
                        name: '$name',
                        month: '$month'
                    },
                    spend: {
                        '$push': '$amount'
                    },
                    total: {
                        '$sum': '$amount'
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        Weekly: [{
                '$match': {
                    week: 12
                }
            },
            {
                '$group': {
                    _id: {
                        name: '$name',
                        week: '$week'
                    },
                    spend: {
                        '$push': '$amount'
                    },
                    total: {
                        '$sum': '$amount'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Sample Response

```
    {
    "Yearly": [{
        "_id": {
            "name": "RINGGO",
            "year": 2017
        },
        "spend": [-3.3, -6.3, -3.3, -6.3, -3.3, -3.3],
        "total": -25.799999999999997
    }],
    "Monthly": [{
        "_id": {
            "name": "RINGGO",
            "month": 3
        },
        "spend": [-3.3, -6.3, -3.3, -6.3, -3.3, -3.3],
        "total": -25.799999999999997
    }],
    "Weekly": [{
        "_id": {
            "name": "RINGGO",
            "week": 12
        },
        "spend": [-6.3, -3.3],
        "total": -9.6
    }]
}
```

You can run the similar aggregation for `Year/Month` and `Year` input values.

> So you can see that there is a different number of items in 
>   MonthlySpends in previous output compared to that shown in the output
>   from the find by name. Also you can see that some of the values are
>   being summed together in MonthlySpends when they shouldn't be.

This happens in `$group` 1 where `$week`  aggregation rolls up each of two dates [15, 16] amount into week 11 and other two dates [22, 23] amount into week 12 later to show up as summed totals in `MonthySpends`.

Comment: Thanks @veeram, this looks very promising.  Please give me a little time to test this evening in a range of scenarios in my application.  Am I right to think that to just get results for `Year/Month` and not `week` I just remove `week: {
            '$week': '$date'
        }` from `$addFields` and then remove the `Weekly` `facet`?

Comment: You are welcome. Please take your time and wait for other solutions too. Yes your understanding is correct. Either you can remove the whole week block of code(`if (request["week"]){..}`) or if you don't include/ have missing week param in request object(`var request = {
  "name":"RINGGO",
  "year": 2017,
  "month":3
};`) which will evaluate `if (request["week"])` to false and thus will not include that code block. –

Comment: sorry to be a pain and I know that this wasn't originally expressed but is there a way to get the date of the spend within the Yearly, monthly, weekly `spend`?  Perhaps `spend` might look like '"spend": [{date:2017-03-26, amount:-3.3}, {date:2017-03-25, amount:-6.3},]' etc, or you may have a better idea

Comment: Its not a problem. You can update your `spend` part of aggregation piepline to  `spend: {
                        '$push': {'date':{ $dateToString: { 'format': "%Y-%m-%d", 'date': '$date' } }, 'amount':'$amount'}
     }`. Uses `$dateToString` operator to format the date.